# Saving response to environment with multiple values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, postman

I'm trying to save these IDs, but they are not getting saved to my environment variables and I'm seeing the console output as:

```
undefined
undefined
```

Json Response

```
{
    "savedIds": [
        95672,
        95673
    ]
}
```

Test

```
for(let i = 0; i< jsonData.savedIds.length; i++) {
pm.environment.set("savedID" + [i+1],jsonData)
console.log(pm.environment.get('savedIds' + [i+1]));
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your code to get JSON data works well such as written here:

```js
let jsonData = {
    "savedIds": [
        95672,
        95673
    ]
};

for(let i = 0; i < jsonData.savedIds.length; i++) {
  console.log(i + ", " + jsonData.savedIds[i]);
};
```

The issue come from the key used with Postman. You are using `savedID` then `savedIds`. So, you will do something like this:

```js
for(let i = 0; i< jsonData.savedIds.length; i++) {
  pm.environment.set("savedID" + [i+1], jsonData.savedIds[i])
  console.log(pm.environment.get('savedID' + [i+1]));
};
```

Comment: I want it to be saved as:
savedID2 = 95672 and savedID3 = 95673

`for(let i = 0; i< jsonData.savedIds.length; i++) {
  pm.environment.set("savedID" + [i+1],jsonData.savedIds)
  console.log(pm.environment.get('savedID' + [i+1]));
};`
Console log:
(2) [95689, 95690]
0: 95689
1: 95690
 
(2) [95689, 95690]
0: 95689
1: 95690

Comment: I just add code for this, I suggest you to check again my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative way of doing the same thing:

```js
jsonData.savedIds.forEach((id, index) => pm.environment.set(`savedID_${index + 1}`, id));
```

or using Lodash in Postman:

```js
_.each(jsonData.savedIds, (id, index) => pm.environment.set(`savedID_${index + 1}`, id));
```